# Receiving SSL certificate errors only from some clients

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

I am receiving SSL certificate errors from Chrome (latest version (23.0.1271.52 beta-m) and Internet Explorer 6 (not used) on my home desktop machine (Windows XP SP2).  In Firefox, the site works fine on this PC.  My laptop and work desktop (both Windows 7) also seem to work just fine.  **Most** SSL website checking sites report that the certificate and chain up to the root CA are setup correctly, but I have come across about 2 that that say I have an invalid certificate but don't give much information on which piece is failing.

I know it used to work properly on this desktop (in Chrome and IE) in the past, but I'm not sure what has changed that is causing the site to fail in these browsers.  Can anyone provide any assistance?  This is driving me nuts!

Screenshot of error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cDD6P.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was surrounding the certificate's hashing algorithm (SHA2-256) which isn't supported by these versions of Windows.

[KB968730](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730) - Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP clients cannot obtain certificates from a Windows Server 2008-based certification authority (CA) if the CA is configured to use SHA2 256 or higher encryption.

Many thanks to the author of this [great article](http://www.cupfighter.net/index.php/2012/03/internet-explorer-cannot-display-the-webpage/) where I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try update windows - there are updates for the certs database that might solve this problem.

Comment: The only update available at this point is to upgrade to Windows XP Service Pack 3.  I think you might be on to something, but really don't want to upgrade and have it not work.  The part that doesn't make sense and is keeping me from trying that is, why would it stop working?

Comment: Because maybe the site changed their cert issuer.
And I think that MS sometimes takes off certs during updates.
You can take a backup image jnust in case you'd want to roll back, or you can try install the Chain Root Cert of this issuer.

Comment: I operate the site and the certificate hasn't changed.  Also, the root and intermediate certs are showing as trusted.

Comment: I've just found that Windows Server 2003 SP2 (both IE and Chrome latest versions) are displaying the same errors.  Driving me nuts.  Anyone have any suggestions?